# How to stop the tick timer or use the same old timer to call same URL with diff parameter?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, timer

I have problem that I use timer to call URL (This URL contain number as parameter) and in first call the timer work fine then I call the method to call the URL with different number ---> the timer start new timer without killing the old one or use it, I have used timer.stop() but this is stop everything.

I need a help how to make this, please help me.

This is my timer code:-

```
public void GetOpentPos1(object sender,string accountID) 
{
    GetOpentPos(sender,accountID);
    DispatcherTimer newTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

    newTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
    //newTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(GetOpentPos);
    newTimer.Tick += new EventHandler((sender1, e) => GetOpentPos(sender,accountID));

    newTimer.Start();

}


private void GetOpentPos (object sender,string accountID)
{
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://x.x.x.x/vertexweb10/webservice.svc/GetOpenPositions?AccountId="+accountID)) as HttpWebRequest;

    request.Method = "GET";

    if (request.Headers == null)
    {
        request.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
    }
    // My code
}
```

I call the second call like this:-

```
GetOpentPos1(sender,accountID);
```

#### Note:

The timer should keep working until I call it again.

Comment: If you are just wanting to call a function at an interval, you don't need to use a timer. You need to use Thread.Sleep(). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Sleep() is extremely inefficient. I typically would not recommend using this approach in a production solution. However, it is probably the simplest solution.

If you are just wanting to call a function at an interval, you don't need to use a timer. You need to use Thread.Sleep(). You can do this like so.

```
public void GetOpentPos1(object sender,string accountID) 
{
    while (1) // loop forever
    {
        GetOpentPos(sender,accountID);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}

private void GetOpentPos (object sender,string accountID)
{
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://x.x.x.x/vertexweb10/webservice.svc/GetOpenPositions?AccountId="+accountID)) as HttpWebRequest;

    request.Method = "GET";

    if (request.Headers == null)
    {
        request.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
    }
// My code
}
```

You can another example for Thread.Sleep at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Its not working because the my application will stuck in infinite while and will not make any other actions, please advice me using timer ?

Comment: Yes, this is the downside of your question. Based on the content of the question, it appeared you were looking for an infinite loop. If you would like to revise your question, I will see if I can adjust my answer.

Comment: To avoid the blocking of your application you could just move this code from the UI Thread